# How to move blob from one table to another?

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I want to move blob from one MySQL table to another table.

I try this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test1 Blob SELECT Blob FROM test");
```

But don't working and try with SELECT, then INSERT, but don't working.

Next question:
If I want not Insert to another table, but update in another table what then do?

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax should be:

```
INSERT INTO test1 (`Blob`) SELECT `Blob` FROM test
```

What you've done here is to alias `test1` as `Blob`. As always [refer to the documentation on `SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) before randomly trying things. As a note, having `Blob` as a column name can be problematic as it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: If I want not Insert to another table, but update in another table what then do it?

Comment: That's a whole other question, but feel free to ask as one.